# Powershell Cmdlets to provide access to new user on shared path in windows 2003

Tags: windows, powershell, active-directory, windows-server-2003, mmc

I am looking to automate the tasks like providing access to a new user on shared path through `Microsoft Computer management console compmgmt.msc` in `windows server 2003`. I am looking for `power shell cmdlets` for the same. Can someone please direct me to a place where I can find these.

Thanks,
Sambhav

Answer (score 1):

On W2K3 you only have PSv1 or 2 and their supported .Net libraries. So you are stuck with those.

Providing access though is just setting permissions, manually or via code. You don't use PS to control the Compmgmt.msc. PS, goals really don't include GUI management.

You can grant permissions on a share, via automation, with no reason to touch a GUI.

The PSv2 (assuming you've got that on the boxes), you only have thee cmdlets
https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/13876.powershell-2-0-cmdlets.aspx

So, from that list it is the...

```
Get-Acl
Set-Acl
```

… cmdlets you are after.

Otherwise, the below can show a different approach.

> How can I set SHARE permissions using powershell v2.0?
>
> https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/ie/en-US/7fd11f99-c45b-4e8f-acb1-bd7df870a811/how-can-i-set-share-permissions-using-powershell-v20

```
 #Creating Security Descriptor
 $sd = ([WMIClass] "Win32_SecurityDescriptor").CreateInstance() 

 #Creating ACE for Authenticated Users and setting it to Security Descriptor
 [System.Security.Principal.NTAccount]$account="NT Authority\Authenticated Users"
 [INT]$rights='1179817'

 $ace = Create-WMIAce $account $rights
 $sd.DACL += @($ace.psobject.baseobject) # append 
 $sd.ControlFlags="0x4" # set SE_DACL_PRESENT flag 

 #Creating ACE for Administrators and setting it to Security Descriptor
 [System.Security.Principal.NTAccount]$account="BUILTIN\Administrators"
 [System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemRights]$rights='FullControl'

 $ace = Create-WMIAce $account $rights
 $sd.DACL += @($ace.psobject.baseobject) # append 
 $sd.ControlFlags="0x4" # set SE_DACL_PRESENT flag 

 #Setting  Share Permissions
 $Share = gwmi win32_share -filter "name='ShareName'"
 $Share.SetShareInfo($Share.MaximumAllowed,$Share.Description,$SD)
```

Comment: Thank you for the information, let me go through them.